# dojo unordered list not showing the bullet images in worklight

Tags: html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I was just trying to make a simple HTML code editor on android using dojo framework on IBM worklight, now when for all other code it is working perfectly fine. But when i try ordered and unordered lists i just dont see the bullets or numbers here i am including snapshots of my work...

[image: dojo code editor view]

[image: result of the previous code]

as you can see that i can not see the bullets on the list items, i dont know if i have to include some images or import something in worklight , because i tried it on jsFiddle and to my surprise it worked(which ofcourse it should) but i dont know why for my case it aint working, i dont know if this is sufficient info for my problem, so if you have any solution and wanna ask some more info please ask...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Worklight stylesheet has a style rule for ul and ol that sets the list-style as none. If you would like the bullet on the list items, you can define rules for ol and ul in your application's stylesheet (htmlProj.css) that will override the existing list-style property value.

Comment: oh damn, din know how i missed that, by the way, my firebug told me that the list style was set to none in wlclient.css, though i dont seem to find it in my project anywhere, must be generated at runtime, do you have idea like where it is generated....?

Comment: It is generated and added to the application when you build. If you wanted to see it, you could add an Android Worklight environment. Then if you expand the `native/assets/www/default/wlclient/css/` directory structure, you'll see wlclient.css